# Laravel, how to manually install package without composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, filezilla

Wanted to install Laravel-Excel (Maatwebsite) package manually without composer, but I dont know how.

Why? Because I have a laravel project in a free hosting server setup by other guy, and I can only access using Filezilla to edit/download/upload the codes.

If only Filezilla allow a command prompt that could use "composer update", then it will be easier.

Comment: So do composer install on your local machine and upload everything including the vendor folder to your hosting.

Comment: problem is, im not allowed to do that

Comment: Allowed to do what? You can't run composer on the computer you're at right now?

Comment: The laravel project is everything inside the server and i dont have it locally. And i am not allowed download everything in the server and reupload the whole thing

Answer (score 18):

I got solution!
I cant use composer on my company because of secure network. But i can download zip form github and install it manual. The below is my example for **HTMLPurifier**:

1. download and extract library mews/purifier to vendor directory [https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier](http://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier)
2. add below line in **vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php**

This sentence will load all of file from vendor/mews/purifier/src and autoload in namespace Mews\Purifier\

```
'Mews\\Purifier\\' => array($vendorDir . '/mews/purifier/src'),
```

Sometime you need add library into **autoload_namespaces.php** intead of, please read in 
  https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

You got Mews\Purifier\Facades\Purifier not found if public config before finish step 3

> $ php artisan vendor:publish
>   --provider="Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider"

3. add below json in **vendor/composer/installed.json**

This for composer history, **providers** and **aliases** will be load in config/app/php for register new provider

```
{
    "name": "mews/purifier",
    "version": "v2.0.12",
    "type": "library",
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Mews\\Purifier\\PurifierServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "Purifier": "Mews\\Purifier\\Facades\\Purifier"
            }
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mews\\Purifier\\": "src/"
        }
    }
},
```

Now you run this config, then vendor/mews/purifier/config will be move to config folder

> $ php artisan vendor:publish
>   --provider="Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider"

Comment: you need to run composer du before vendor:publish to autoload package.

Answer (score 14):

1. Add the package to the vendor folder. You can upload it using filezilla
2. Add a reference in \vendor\composer\autoload_namespaces.php
3. Add a reference in \vendor\composer\autoload_psr4.php

Source [laravel.io](https://laravel.io/forum/03-29-2015-manually-install-laravelcomposer-packages)

Comment: no need to run php artisan vendor:publish in laravel?

Answer (score 2):

it's easy to do it by following this
download the package and set the files in app folder

```
YourProject/app/Laravel-Excel/
```

and then add the path to composer.json in autoload

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
        "app/Laravel-Excel"
    ],
    ...
},
```

Run the `composer dump-autoload`

the solution refs to  this question  [referance answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488913/how-to-use-laravel-libraries-in-laravel-project-without-composer)

Answer (score 1):

download the package locally and then upload the package folder (found under vendor) along with the updated composer.json

Comment: I tried your method yesterday. Download the package, take the maatwebsite folder in vendor, edit config/app, edit composer.json, but it produce an error

Comment: Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' not found. I already put Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class, at providers in config/app and 'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class, at aliases. And I already uploaded the vendor file

Comment: are all the packages currently installed working properly or they're all throwing the same error?

Comment: all the other package that currently installed is working perfectly, just this Laravel/Excel package are not

Comment: I think you need to run compose dump-autoload on your local machine and re-upload the entire vendor folder

Comment: Produces error Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' not found, done exactly what you told. Here what I did, I make a new laravel project file, install Laravel/Excel (Maatwebsite) package, edit config/app, composer publish. Okay so far locally done. Now I upload the vendor(maatwebsite), edit config/app, edit composer.json, upload excel.php into config\

Comment: Hey Ali are you in the Beirut area?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how strict the server is, you could SSH into your Server. But doing it locally then uploading the required files is usually the way to go.

You might need to run composer autodump if you don't wipe the cache.

Comment: The laravel project is everything inside the server and i dont have it locally. And i am not allowed download everything in the server and reupload the whole thing, how to do it manually?

Comment: @begineeeerrrr If you don't have it locally you could create a new laravel project and composer install the package you want. Find it in the vendor file and upload it to the site. Edit the required live config/app so that its links to its ServiceProvider and Facades and then reupload that.

If you still get an error then a composer dumpautoload is required.

You should, if you can, have the whole project locally and work using XAMPP or something similar using a vhost. Much better productivity.

Comment: Produces error Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' not found, done exactly what you told. Here what I did, I make a new laravel project file, install Laravel/Excel (Maatwebsite) package, edit config/app, composer publish. Okay so far locally done. Now I upload the vendor(maatwebsite), edit config/app, edit composer.json, upload excel.php into config\

Answer (score 0):

If everything works on local environment then copy your package and composer folder to server which is located at vendor

Answer (score -3):

upload \vendor\maatwebsite
copy \vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\config\excel.php   to   \config\excel.php