# how to install git-hub packages in laravel online live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

i want to install git-hub below package:

```
" realrashid/sweet-alert "
```

**package  in my laravel online running project** 
**my project running in cpanel shared host**

Any help in this ?

Comment: You can also manually install package without package.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566233/laravel-how-to-manually-install-package-without-composer)

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect SSH / Terminal
2. Go to your project root folder like `cd prohect-path`
3. command run `composer require realrashid/sweet-alert`

if composer is not install then first install composer in your live server.

or

you can follow step **@Mo5tafa**

Answer (score 0):

Install whole composer packages locally, and move your project to zip/tar.gz file and then upload your zip file project to shared host (with cpanel file manager or filezilla), finally unzip your project.