# Is there a way to add new package to laravel project without using command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I downloaded mews/captcha package as a zip file and I want to add it to my laravel project.
Does anyone know how I can do this and which folders/files I need to update for it to work?
(I can't use composer require/composer update)

Thanks!

Comment: If you can't use composer commands does that also mean you can't use the composer autoloader? Or can you use it but not update it?

Comment: I can't use composer autoloader either :\

Comment: assuming that you have an autoload file (but can't use any composer commands to update it) then the above should answer your question. If you don't even have an autoload file and the composer autoloader then Laravel itself should not be working

Comment: What is the correct way to do it with composer autoloader?

Comment: Extract the contents of the zip in your vendor directory and run `composer dump-autoload` if you can use that command. If you can't use the command follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59713178/487813)

Comment: _Note_ that this package _is_ available in composer: https://packagist.org/packages/mews/captcha

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. Regarding the second solution, the answer refers to a specific library and I don't know how it should look with the library I need. Do you know which reference I should add? @apokryfos

Comment: The source composer.json of that package is [here](https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha/blob/master/composer.json). You should try to match what is in there in the `autoload` section e.g. in your case you should add `'Mews\\Captcha\\' => array($vendorDir . '/mews/captcha/src'),` the 2nd parameter should match exactly where you extracted the library. However this one has in addition a `files` entry which I suggest you manually require where you need it (if you need it)